# Как можно сместить ResizeMode?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно закруглённое, но при свойстве ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" (Немного выходит за рамки окна)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну немного в лево и вверх ResizeMode сместить хочется.

Пробовал что то типа такого

```
<Style TargetType="ResizeMode">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 10 0 0"/>
</Style>
```

Но так не работает : (

Comment: вот похожий на твой вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095676/change-the-color-of-the-resizegrip-in-wpf . Скорее всего тебе надо перееопределить шаблон для ```ResizeGrip```

Comment: @Pekor, спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: можешь ли кинуть ссылку на гитхаб с проектом, если есть?

Comment: @Pekor, https://github.com/crushednat123/templateStart   (на счёт ResizeGrip, я пока думаю как сделать прозрачным ResizeModel и оставить видимым ResizeGrip)